# Applying BCs for PDE Separation of Variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

At the link below, after applying the boundary conditions it seems that the “Answer” post finds that $T(r,z)=z$.
[Solving 2-D steady state heat transfer in cylindrical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349183/solving-2-d-steady-state-heat-transfer-in-cylindrical-coordinates)

However, doesn’t that not comply with the boundary condition that T be zero at $r=1$?

I am working on a very similar problem and any clarification would be very helpful.

Comment: I didn't complete reading the question in your link but I see that the condition is $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}|_{(0,z)}= 0$ and it agrees with $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}|= 0$ , I am not sure what do you mean by $T$ be zero at $r=1$ .

Comment: Thank you! My mistake. It has a different boundary condition than my problem (which sets curved wall at T=0)